# Export the phone number with country code to the excel become the formula | maatwebsite | excel | Laravel | PHP

Tags: php, excel, maatwebsite-excel

I am working on the Laravel application where I export the information of the client to excel by using the maatwebsite/excel package.

Everything is working as expected. But when I start to export the client's ***phone number with country code***(which obviously includes the plus symbol) the value under the excel field becomes the formula section.

**ClientsExport.php**

```
class ClientsExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, WithMapping, WithColumnFormatting
{
    // ...
    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'Name',
            'Identification type',
            'Tax ID',
            'Email',
            'Address',
            'Country',
            'Department',
            'Zip',
            'Fax',
            'Phone',
            'Mobile',
            'Date'
        ];
    }

    public function columnFormats(): array
    {
        return [
            'H' => 0,
            'I' => 0,
            'J' => '@',
            'K' => '@',
            'L' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY,
        ];
    }
    // ...
}
```

I even try both general and text format(i.e 'General' or '@') but still have the same error. Field J and K have phone and mobile value respectively.

The data is export to the excel file. I think this is the default behavior of the excel file i.e when we click on the field value which prefix with a plus symbol then it automatically becomes the formula bar section.

Can I get rid of it and change the behavior? Thanx in advance.

Comment: Replace the plus symbol before doing anything else - “00” may be an idea...

Comment: I think this will not give the correct information about the phone number.

Comment: And there was me thinking 0041 was equivalent to +41 ...

Comment: But my client doesn't think that.

Comment: you can insert ' to the begining of the phone numbers.

Comment: In case if I select data from the cell which is prefix with single quote then single will also copied?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your custom value binder and replace the `=` sign to prevent your value to become an excel formula.

Here is an example:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCustomValueBinder;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Cell;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DefaultValueBinder;

class ClientsExport extends DefaultValueBinder implements WithCustomValueBinder
{
    private Collection $users;

    private string $title;

    public function __construct() { }

    public function bindValue(Cell $cell, $value)
    {
        // only replace for column K and J with rows > 1
        // let's just say the first line is the header
        if (in_array($cell->getColumn(), ['J', 'K']) && $cell->getRow() > 1) {
            $value = str_replace('=', '', $value);
        };

        // else return default behavior
        return parent::bindValue($cell, $value);
    }
}
```

reference [Maatwebsite - Column Formatting - Value Binders](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/column-formatting.html#value-binders)